# Memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++

I am confused about the memory allocation in C++. Can anyone guide me as to where each of the variable in the below snippet is getting allocated. How can I determine what is getting allocated on stack and what gets allocated on heap. Is there any good web reference for learning this.

```
   class Sample {
    private:
        int *p;
    public: 
        Sample() {
            p = new int;
        }
    };

    int* function(void) {
        int *p;
        p = new int;
        *p = 1;

        Sample s;

        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Well first you should give up this notion of stack and heap (they are not that useful in C++). There are three types of variables `automatic storage duration`, `static storage duration` and `dynamic storage duration`.

Comment: It should be noted for future searchers that the author, admittedly not knowing the answer to their question, did not realize they got a stack of incorrect answers and simply picked the smartest sounding one.  It's not the correct answer to the question asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's created via `new`, it's in the heap. If it's inside of a function, and it's not `static`, then it's on the stack. Otherwise, it's in global (non-stack) memory.

```
class Sample {
    private:
        int *p;
    public: 
        Sample() {
            p = new int;  // p points to memory that's in the heap
        }

       // Any memory allocated in the constructor should be deleted in the destructor; 
       // so I've added a destructor for you:
        ~Sample() { delete p;}

        // And in fact, your constructor would be safer if written like this:
        // Sample() : p(new int) {}
        // because then there'd be no risk of p being uninitialized when
        // the destructor runs.
        //
        // (You should also learn about the use of shared_ptr,
        //  which is just a little beyond what you've asked about here.)
    };

    int* function(void) {
        static int stat; // stat is in global memory (though not in global scope)
        int *p;          // The pointer itself, p, is on the stack...
        p = new int;     // ... but it now points to memory that's in the heap
        *p = 1;

        Sample s;        // s is allocated on the stack

        return p;
    }

}

int foo; // In global memory, and available to other compilation units via extern

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
// Your program here...
```

Comment: does all the allocation apart from new happen during compile time?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It's more accurate to say that the space for the variables is *reserved* at compile time, whether on the stack or in global memory. Of course, initialization (that is, executing the constructors) always happens at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: To add, `sizeof` class should be determined by the compiler to reserve space. That is the reason, `forward declaration of class B` isn't enough when you have `B obj;` as a member of `class A`.

Comment: This is actually wrong.  If it's allocated with 'new' then it's on the *free store*.  The free store is different from the heap although sometimes the free store is implemented by using the heap.  What is allocated with *malloc* is actually what is on the heap.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: While there is *sometimes* a difference in the technical definitions of the terms "heap" and "free store", in common usage the term "heap" is used for any kind of dynamically-managed memory, to no disadvantage to software engineers that I'm aware of. "Common usage" here does not include those who implement compilers and runtime libraries, of course. (For what it's worth, Wikipedia says in part: "Usually, memory is allocated from a large pool of unused memory area called the heap (also called the free store.)" -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Details

Comment: @Dan: It's not really correct to say that stack space is reserved during compile time.  The size of the automatic locals in each function is calculated at compile time, and the size of the first thread's stack is set by a linker option, but on pretty much all major OSes, the stack size for other threads is set when the thread is created, and allocation from the stack actually takes place on entry to any function using automatic variables (and possibly also mid-function, if `_alloca` is used.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I was trying to be brief, but you're right that the stack itself is not "reserved" by the compiler. A better way to word it would be that the compiler arranges to reserve a fixed amount of space on the stack for each stack-based variable.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: For what it's worth, my first exposure to the term "heap" (as a pool from which memory can be allocated) was in a language distinct from C or C++. Many folks use "heap" in the sense of abstract data structures; others need to draw a linguistic distinction between the areas of memory managed by `new`/`delete` and `malloc`/`free`, respectively. Had `new`/`delete` been designed first, perhaps the purists would be using "free store" to refer to `malloc`'s memory pool, while others would still be using "heap" to refer to either (unless the context requires a distinction.)

Comment: @Dan - personal history lessons aside, the terms used by C++ developers to differentiate between the two, which may be completely unrelated and not just semantically unrelated, is "free store" for new/delete and "heap" for malloc/free.  My comment stands, as does the negative rating for giving an erroneous answer.

Comment: @Noah, no one is suggesting that `new/delete` and `malloc/free` use the same storage pool. Insisting that different terms *must* be used to distinguish the two is exactly like insisting that we must no longer speak of " **the** stack" because, of course, there can be multiple stacks within a program.

Comment: @Dan - Sorry, that's a silly statement to make.  Treating automatic variables like automatic variables doesn't cause any problems.  Treating heap allocated items like free-store allocated items though, that will.

Comment: @Noah, then let's agree to be mutually silly towards each other, and leave it at that. I think most developers get past the "new != malloc" and "delete != free" issue pretty quickly, and I see no reason why a new semantics is needed to address that problem.

Comment: It's not a new term.  You should note that while "free store" appears in the C++ standard index, referring to new/delete, the term "heap" appears nowhere.

Comment: @Noah, that is far from definitive. The standard mentions `malloc` many times in relation to `new`, yet it does not specify that any two distinct terms must be used for `malloc`'s memory pool vs. `new`'s pool. There are *many* common terms that do not appear in the Standard as they are commonly used: "Stack", "method", "subclass", "superclass", etc. There are multitudes of developers who use the term "heap" as I have. Semantic pedantry will not save developers who don't know that `free` and `delete` are not equivalent; it may only confuse them further. Please, find other windmills to tilt at.

Comment: Yes, a lot of developers use incorrect terminology just like you have.  Just look at all the other responses.  They're wrong as well.  You are wrong, plain and simple, and have obviously managed to derail a newbie with your ignorance.  Worse yet, you refuse to learn from your mistakes even with the piles of evidence counted against you.  If you want to be wrong, fine for you, but please do refrain from spreading your stupidity.  It is especially bad when someone says, "I don't know these terms," and you then set about misleading them with incorrect definitions.

Comment: And, BTW for those searching here for answers, the standard does not specify the relationship between the free store and heap because it should be up to the implementation to decide this relationship.

Comment: These are, really, my last two comments on the subject. 1) It seems that the definitive document for Noah's stance is not the Standard, but a non-normative article by Herb Sutter that Noah has linked to: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm. However, Herb doesn't explain *why* a distinction between "heap" and "free store" is so crucial.  If the semantic distinction were critical to the language definition, it should be encoded in the Standard itself. It is not. (Hinted at, yes; perhaps even implied, but only through a generous reading.)

Comment: 2) Yes, malloc and new may use different pools, but so what? We know they're not interchangeable. They're **functionally incompatible.** The rest is implementation detail. *Many* in the C++ community, including Stroustrup, seem OK with "heap" as a synonym for "free store". See (e.g.) http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.com/2007/02/c-free-store-versus-heap.html and http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/abstraction-and-machine.pdf. Noah is free to call me or Bjarne stupid, but I doubt that either of us is (not that I'm comparing myself to Bjarne.)

Answer (score 1):

Where ever `new` keyword is there it get allocated on heap.

```
class Sample {
private:
    int *p; //allocated on stack
public: 
    Sample() {
        p = new int; //integer gets allocated on heap
    }
};

int* function(void) {
    int *p;        //allocated on stack
    p = new int;   //integer gets allocated on heap
    *p = 1;

    Sample s;      //allocated on stack

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any thing with `new` is on heap. `s` of `Sample s` gets memory allocated on stack.

Comment: Not exactly. For example, if I do `new Sample()`, then `Sample`'s `p` member is allocated on the heap, even though it isn't allocated with `new`. :)

Comment: Ok. But how about the static member variables ? They don't belong to any particular class instance. Where would they reside ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample {
private:
    int *p; 
public: 
    Sample() {
        p = new int; //<--allocated on the heap. Anything created with operator new is allocated on the heap.
    }
};

int* function(void) {
    int *p; //<-- pointer is allocated on the stack as it is a local variable
    p = new int; //<-- the value pointed to by p is allocated on the heap (new operator)
    *p = 1;

    Sample s; //<--Allocated on the stack (local variable).

    return p;
}
```